# How do you use a current to voltage converter to probe a specific part of a circuit?

Tags: current, analog, probe

I want to probe a part of this circuit that I have using a current to voltage converter. Problem is, I don't know if I'm doing it properly. Most current to voltage converters I've seen take an input current directly from the source load, but I haven't seen one that takes input current from a junction.

Here's the part which I wanted to probe (Ids) - https://i.stack.imgur.com/2MgZ7.jpg 
 And here's the attempt I've made to probe it using a current to voltage converter - https://i.stack.imgur.com/TA5zc.jpg

I have a gut feeling that I'm doing it wrong.

P.S. not an engineering student.

Comment: Generally you need to break the circuit to sense current. You can run the current through the center of a a hall-effect based current sensor or you can use a small resistor in series with your current. You measure the voltage drop across the resistor with a mV meter and calculate the current based on that. Are you interested in DC readings (meter) or do you need to see fluctuations with time (oscilloscope).

Comment: What is the purpose of the circuit?

Comment: @mkeith, A clever trick is to measure the voltage drop across an existing resistor with known resistance on the board... then its resistance can be as high as it is:)

Comment: @Circuitfantasist yes but I already looked at the circuit. No such luck. The only available item is a potentiometer.

Comment: @BruceAbbott Biasing circuit for an Ion-sensitive Field effect transistor. U3 is supposed to be activated/connected to U2 and the ISFET gate ONLY when Vgs has surpassed the threshold voltage OR Vds and Ids are above zero (i.e. when the ISFET is operating in the linear region.).

Comment: IMO U3 wil be always "activated" and the threshold voltage will be always surpassed since U3 and gate-source port are inserted in the negative feedback loop of U2... and it will do all the best to "suck" the required current from the FET source. Only I wonder what is the need of the fixed-gain non-inverting amplifier U3 since U2 provides the total gain needed. I think you can remove it.

Comment: Regarding the current measurement, I think you do not need a special op-amp current-to-voltage converter. You can insert the current-sensing resistor between the lower variable resistor (rheostat) and U2 inverting input and measure the voltage drop across it (or simply the voltage of the resistor right end since its left end is virtually grounded). The current in the input and output circuit is the same (a property of inverting circuits). Another trick is to measure the voltage drop across the ammeter (the voltage of its left end since the right end is virtually grounded).

Comment: The ammeter can be also moved to the input circuit and thus the FET source will be really virtuallly grounded.